# Addition of time variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add two time variables, but I have one's data type as `time` and another one is as `int` using stored procedure.

```
declare 
@final int,
@hrs time,
@late_time int;  

SELECT @late_time = (SUM(Break_TB.Break_Time)+SUM(Break_TB.Late_time)) from Break_TB where User_Id='NSK-1007' and Status = 'Approved';
SELECT @hrs = convert(varchar(8),dateadd(ms,datediff(ms,log_tb.First_Login,Logout),8),114) from Log_TB where User_Id='NSK-1007';
```

Now I want to add `@hrs` and `@late_time` and put it into `@final`.

How do I do that?

Comment: _"i want to two time variables"_ ?? Also, since is not related to ASP.NET remove the tag but add the rdbms(f.e. SQL-Server 2008).

Comment: You seem to have some working code. Why isn't that code working?

Comment: it works properly .. but how i add that two variable  hrs and late_time when i try to make addition of them sql gives me error as :Operand type clash: time is incompatible with int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `@final int` should be a `@final time`. That end result should be a `time` in my opinion.

Then use [`dateadd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) to add the date and the hour component together. Specify the integer is 'hours':

```
set @final = dateadd(hour, @hrs, @late_time)
```